# Can't establish connect to MySQL over localhost with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I've been attempting to set up MAMP (normal edition) and connect to the MySQL database using PHP, but I can't seem to get the connection right. It's running on localhost, the user 'test' is on localhost, and has the privileges of SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE. Apache is using port 80, and MySQL 3306. Where have I gone wrong? Oh, and yes, I've tried using 127.0.0.1 but to no avial.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", “test”, “development”) or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db(“login_test”) or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

EDIT: I have verified I can connect to MySQL from the terminal.
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot

Comment: you really have these quotes `“`, `”` on your codes?

Comment: replace `“` quotes with `"` they are causing issue.

Comment: Try just `"localhost"` instead of `"localhost:3306"`.

Comment: try connecting from command line first. `/path/to/mysql -h localhost -u test -p`. Enter the password when asked. Oh, and yes, what is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: @Jigar Not an error per say, the page dies with "Could not connect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace “ quotes with " i run your code successfully but i changed “ by "

```
 <?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("login_test") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}

echo var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Seems like my editing program (Adobe's Brackets) decided it wanted to use the wrong type of quotes.

Answer (score -1):

mysql_query is not in use anymore, change all your mysql_

use mysqli_query($connection, "Query") or PDO statements

Comment: how do you know, the `mysql` is not enabled and the `mysqli` extension is enabled ? this is not a solution to the answer.

Comment: Jigar, you don't need to know, its not about whether you enable it or not, it is not supported anymore. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: This could be an answer, as he mentions that he has everything set up right, and just couldn't connect

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean it is removed already. It will be removed in newer versions of PHP, so it is not recommended to use it in new written code.

Comment: Well, it is already removed since 5.5, which most probably is older than the version which the guy is using. Could be an answer, not ruling this probability out.

Comment: `5.5.0 - This function will generate an E_DEPRECATED error.` It will still work.

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can try it yourself.